# What is the alternative to BubbleLayout(Deprecated) of Mapbox android SDK for info window on Markers Selection?

Tags: android, infowindow, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

I want to pop up info window on the marker when selected, to show information about the markered location on Mapbox map in android, something like this:
[image: example]

I tried this code [link](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-info-window/) but here the bubble layout is depricated and due to which I am having error messages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to show info window with the new SDK. Try to implement it using RecyclerView [RecyclerViewOnMapActivity](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/labs/RecyclerViewOnMapActivity.java) . And this way you get full customization and an option to click on inner views inside your info view.

Comment: Can you please have an explanation through an example on ReclerViewOnMapActivity?

Comment: Please download and try the demo app(Find RecyclerView on map example there). https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo. It just draws recyclerview on top of mapview. Every time you click on symbol, you scroll recyclerview to the selected position. And vice-verca (not implemented here, but easy to do).